# Angular 4 - Refresh after action

Tags: angular

I am creating a sample CRUD app in MEAN. Whole of it is done, but I am not able to refresh the view after every operation. For example, in my component I have this for delete and read:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.getUsers();
}
getUsers() {
  this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(res => { this.users = res.data; });
}

deleteUser() {
  this.userService.deleteUser(this.selectedUser).subscribe(this.selectedUser = null);
}
```

As you can see, I do the getUsers inside `ngOnInit`. I try to do the this.getUsers inside the subscribe of the deleteuser but it doesnt allow me to do so and says getusers is not defined. How can I refresh the view?

Comment: What's the error message/stack trace exactly when it says getusers is not defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of subscribe() is a function. This function fires when your observable emits something (in this case your observable is an http request, so when the http request is successful). Within that function you can re-call your getUsers method

```
deleteUser(){        
    this.userService.deleteUser(this.selectedUser).subscribe(res => {
       // http request was successful, perform logic in here
       this.getUsers();
    });
}
```